# Mathematical Induction that seems v difficult

Tags: linear-algebra, induction

i have a problem with a mathematical induction but i find it really hard to solve:

Q: $\sum_1^n iax^i = \frac{ax(1-x^{n}-nx^{n}+nx^{n+1})}{(1-x)^{2}}$

n is all positive integer

I know it can be solved using simple maths but i can't seem to find the key, i have tried various combinations but it doesn't work.

What I have:

I have done up the basis step, letting n = 1

$\sum_1^n iax^{i} = 1ax^{1} = ax (LHS)$

$\frac{ax(1-x-x+x^{2})}{(1-x)^{2}}$ 
= $\frac{ax(1-2x-x^{2})}{1-2x-x^{2}}$
= ax (RHS)

since both side as the same, the proposition is true:

$\sum_1^k iax^{i} = kax^{k}$

Inductive step :

$\sum_1^{k+1} iax^{i} = \sum_1^k iax^{i} + (k+1)ax^{k+1}
= kax^{k} + (k+1)ax^{k+1}$

So is this what i am suppose to prove? :

$kax^{k} + (k+1)ax^{k+1} = \frac{ax(1-x^{k+1}-(k+1)x^{k+1}+(k+1)x^{k+1+1}}{(1-x)^{2}}$

i have tried factorising, eliminating and all kinds of possible methods to my knowledge but i can't seem to find a solution to this, it's frustrating since i know it should be able to  be solved by simple maths. Someone please guide me to solve questions like this. Thank you very much

Comment: Try using the `$` symbol either side of an equation for inline maths or two `$` symbols either side for an equation on its own line.

Comment: hi, okay i will try to edit it, the codes are confusing to me

Comment: `$\sum_1^n iax^i = (ax(1−x^n−nx^n+nx^{n+1}))/(1−x)^2$` gives: $\sum_1^n iax^i = (ax(1−x^n−nx^n+nx^{n+1}))/(1−x)^2$ and `$$\sum_{i=1}^n iax^i = \frac{ax(1−x^n−nx^n+nx^{n+1})}{(1−x)^2}$$` gives: $$\sum_{i=1}^n iax^i = \frac{ax(1−x^n−nx^n+nx^{n+1})}{(1−x)^2}$$

Comment: yes, i finally figured it out, thanks a lot!

Comment: To be fair to me, you can see by the time on my first comment that I was the first person to help you and I first took time to help you with using $\LaTeX$ commands in your question before I was able to start typing out my answer. By the time I started typing my actual answer, someone else had already posted a complete one.

Comment: @aria_ratio: how many more edits will you make ?

Comment: it's okay, thanks a lot for your help too! i didn't even realise my  steps was wrong and this explains why i can't even solve it despite spending days; i was trying to prove something that is not equal!

Comment: @sush, sry i am too new to this and kept editing.

Comment: Oh I was just joking. I also am too new and know little math than you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number $x$ can be $0$. It cannot be $1$.

I will forget about $a$, you can put it back in.

The induction assumption is that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^k ix^i =\frac{x(1-x^{k}-kx^{k}+kx^{k+1})}{(1-x)^{2}}.\tag{1}$$
We want to show that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} ix^i =\frac{x(1-x^{k+1}-(k+1)x^{k+1}+(k+1)x^{k+2})}{(1-x)^{2}}.\tag{2}$$ 
Note that the left-hand side of (2) is the left-hand side of (1), with $(k+1)x^{k+1}$ added.
So we need to show that
$$\frac{x(1-x^{k}-kx^{k}+kx^{k+1})}{(1-x)^{2}}+(k+1)x^{k+1}=\frac{x(1-x^{k+1}-(k+1)x^{k+1}+(k+1)x^{k+2})}{(1-x)^{2}}.\tag{3}$$
Bring the left-hand side of (3) to the common denominator $(1-x)^2$ and simplify. It helps to know your target.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, it turns out that I can solve LHS to prove  equality in RHS, seems like i need to brush up on my concept since my induction step is wrong. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly the following is a correct statement:

$$\sum_{i=1}^k iax^i = \frac{ax(1−x^k−kx^k+kx^{k+1})}{(1−x)^2}$$

You need to fix yours which says

$$\sum_{i=1}^k iax^i = kax^k$$

which is incorrect, and then see what happens next.

Comment: What is that "that" here?

Comment: @Sush aria_ratio has a line in his question that says $$\sum_{i=1}^k iax^i = kax^k$$ which is incorrect. I've clarified my answer, thanks for the tip.